# How do I parse a time string to a specific timezone?

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

I've this string:

> Sunday, Oct 7 4:00pm

When I use `Time.parse`, Ruby assumes the timezone is UTC. How do I tell Ruby to give me -0700 timezone? I've tried using

```
tz.utc_to_local(Time.parse(string))
```

but I still get the UTC +0000 time zone back.

Comment: What is the time zone of your input?

Comment: Err, the server is in +0000 zone, the input itself is in pacific time zone, but I'm not able to convey that info to Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

**"When parsing time information it’s important to never do it without specifying the time zone."**

That gem of an advice is from this useful blogpost : [Working with time zones in Ruby on Rails](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails).

Irrespective of whether you are using rails or not, the time string always has a timezone attached to it. In your case, you are assuming that the time string has a -0700 offset, but not passing the timezone information to the parse method (which is assuming it is UTC).

```
> Rails.application.config.time_zone
=> "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"
```

This is because I have the following config:

```
config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'

> string = "Sunday, Oct 7 4:00pm"
=> "Sunday, Oct 7 4:00pm"
> Time.parse(string)
=> 2012-10-07 16:00:00 -0600
> Time.parse(string).zone
=> "MDT"
```

Works the same way in pure ruby as well:

```
> require 'time'
=> true
> Time.local( 2012, 10, 07 )
=> 2012-10-07 00:00:00 -0600
> Time.local( 2012, 10, 07 ).zone
=> "MDT" 
> string = "Sunday, Oct 7 4:00pm"
=> "Sunday, Oct 7 4:00pm"
> Time.parse(string)
=> 2012-10-07 16:00:00 -0600
> Time.parse(string).zone
=> "MDT"
```

Comment: 1. I'm not using Rails. 2. I don't see where you're setting your time zone in the third example, so I'm assuming #zone just returns your machine's zone.

Comment: Yup. ruby process gets the local machine's timezone.

Comment: The server is on a UTC timezone, but I want to parse it as -0700 time zone, hence the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your timezone is set correctly

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Time.parse should default to the current time zone but you can also try

```
Time.parse('####').in_time_zone
```

Comment: Isn't that specific to rails?  The question does not mention rails.

Comment: Yup, its activesupport specific but so is Time.parse

Comment: @pguardiario I've neither rails or activesupport in the project.